# How to change timestamp format

Tags: bash

File has the following data and want to remove the 'T' and '-07:00' in the Timestamp field

```
407358186|2014-05-16T08:14:00-07:00|993827047
407358186|2014-05-15T08:58:00-07:00|993335621
407358186|2014-05-13T06:13:00-07:00|992181538
407358186|2014-05-11T19:58:00-07:00|991523532
```

Expected output result

```
407358186|2014-05-16 08:14:00|993827047
407358186|2014-05-15 08:58:00|993335621
407358186|2014-05-13 06:13:00|992181538
407358186|2014-05-11 19:58:00|991523532
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed.

```
cat file | sed 's/T/\ /g' | sed 's/-07:00//g'
```

The first pipe simply replaces all T's with spaces, and the second pipe eliminates all instances of the string `-07:00`.

I'm assuming since you're removing the -07:00 that you are not interested in any timezone sensitive data. If you were, you would not remove it, and hence I am able to justify hardcoding '-07:00' into the answer.

Changing timestamps from other timezones would require code which is a bit more involved.